# Wakanda MySQL TEXT data type

Tags: wakanda

Can't get data from MySQL field with data type "text".
It just return empty value, for other string type (char, varchar) it's returning a value as expected.

Any help would be highly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've dug into this, and indeed there is a bug on the Pro Connector:
- The `Text` type is not properly managed

We' ll fix this asap.

In the meantime, you could use the following workaround (it's not perfect however) -

---

Workaround:

To manage specifically the text type, for now you could use the Mysql Wakanda driver. When using it text type are handled as `blob` type you might parse as string.

```
var sql = require('waf-sql');
var params = {
   hostname: '192.168.XX.XX',
   port: xx,
   user: 'xx',
   password: 'xx',
   database: 'xx',
   ssl: false,
   dbType: 'mysql'
};
var session = sql.connect(parms);
var query = "select txt from TextType";
var res = session.execute(query);
var rows = res.getAllRows();
rows[0].txt.toString()
```

It's not as advanced as the Pro Connector but it allows you to retrieve your elements.

---

EDIT :

The bug has been fixed and will be included in the next major Wakanda version. I'll keep u posted here when the release date is defined.

BR
Fred
Wakanda Team

Comment: After checking the doc it appears that indeed the Text type is not yet supported . I ask the tech team for confirmation and get back to you asap.

Comment: @user3063965  please read my answer (my comment just above is not longer valid )

Comment: FrédéricG, The above your solution not working with a general wak-sql library? I don't have any pro connector.